# Test a forked Github project by Travis?

Tags: javascript, git, github, travis-ci

[If I fork a project](https://github.com/abdelouahabb/CodeMirror), and make changes on it, how can I let Travis build the project?

I forked it, it will wait until I make a pull request to give me the build status, but I should test it independently to make the pull request? Because the icon (build|passing) follows the initial project, and not the forked one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You go to [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/), log in (using your github account) and then follow the following simple guide:

> Enable your projects below by flicking the switch, add a `.travis.yml` to your project, and push a new commit to GitHub.

This will lead to your own travis build, independent of the original project and you won't have to wait for any pull requests to be merged.

You'll find the specifications for your `.travis.yml` on [docs.travis-ci.com](http://docs.travis-ci.com/) if you want to do further changes, since you forked a project that already contains one you're all set for now.

Once this is all setup you can adapt the URL in the `readme.md` file to point to your travis build

Comment: then, the logo that shows it passed, it is about the one i forked and not the original one? (the screenshot http://imgur.com/6wDHQLg )

Comment: You need to adapt this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdelouahabb/CodeMirror/master/README.md on the 2nd line and change the URL to your travis build URL. Currently the file still contains the build URL of the original project.